# mysql - get details from 2 tables with 1 query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 mysql tables:

The first table  **table1**:

```
| ID | NAME   |
| 1  | cat    |
| 2  | mouse  |
| 3  | mouse  |
| 4  | mouse  |
| 5  | mouse  |
| 6  | mouse  |
```

The secound table  **table2**:

```
| ID | NAME_NA   |
| 1  | cat       |
| 2  | mouse     |
| 3  | cd_rom    |
| 4  | dvd_rw    |
| 5  | house     |
```

And i want to output this :

```
mouse    -   5 entries
cat      -   1 entry
cd_rom   -   0 entries
dvd_rw   -   0 entries
house    -   0 entries
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use a LEFT JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```
   SELECT x.name_na AS name,
          COALESCE(COUNT(y.name), 0) AS num_entries
     FROM TABLE2 x
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 y ON y.name = x.name_na
```

...to get:

```
name     num_entries
--------------------
mouse    5 
cat      1
cd_rom   0
dvd_rw   0
house    0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `table1`.`NAME`, IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) as entries FROM
`table2` LEFT JOIN `table1` ON `table1`.`NAME` = `table2`.`NAME_NA`
GROUP BY `table1`.`NAME`;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` creates rows for each item in the "left" table (`table2` here) even if there's no match in `table1`, and also will create multiple rows for an item in `table2` if there are multiple matching rows in `table1` for that item.

Then if you `GROUP BY` the name and use a `COUNT()` function, you can get the count of how many matches each item in `table2` has in `table1`.

The `IFNULL()` is utilized because `COUNT()` will return `NULL` if there weren't any matches for that item in `table1`, so we substitute in `0` instead.